# Triple boot with Ubuntu Fedora and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot, fedora

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed in a dual boot as of now. I'd like to install Fedora alongside and maybe someday kill Ubuntu too.

So, my questions are:

1. Can I triple boot with these three OSs
2. Can I shift from Ubuntu to Fedora and get the same software in Fedora? Like, is there a script that takes the list of software out from Ubuntu and then I can feed the list to `yum` in Fedora? Will this work? Or do I have to do the software thing manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can install triple boot, instructions to do that, are identical to dual booting.  As for having the same software on both Ubuntu and Fedora that entirely depends if a version of the software exists on both.

Comment: @Ramhound Dual booting Ubuntu and Windows was as easy as choosing an option. Does Fedora have something like that for triple boot? If not, will installing grub from ubuntu live cd work?

Comment: My experience Grub is used in almost every case of Linux distrubution.  The only different between dual booting and triple booting is an additional system partition and an additional grub entry.  In both cases Windows is loaded by chain loading grub and the windows loader as expected.